# How can I match a regular expression in Python up to a certain character, and return None if not match?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'd want to know if it's possible to match a regular expression until a particular character (':') but avoiding negative logical expressions like [^:]* cause I'd like it to return None if not matches encountered. See an example of what it's expected:

```
import re
string='AbcS:sdaf'
pattern='whatever needed' # match all up to : 
re.search(pattern, string).group()

'AbcS'

string2='AbcSsdaf'
pattern2='whatever needed' # match all up to : 
re.search(pattern2, string2).group()

None
```

In other post i've seen some answers mencioning pattern='[^:]*' but this is not what I want because returns all the string if there is not a ':' in the string.

Thank you all

Comment: You could use: `a = re.search('^.*?(?=:)', string); b = a.group() if a else None;print(b)`

Comment: The quickest pattern you may use is `^([^:]*):`. The greedy `*` will make it match 0 or more chars other than `:` in one go, and then `:` will require `:` to be present in  the string. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^(?=.*:)[^:]*
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2Uxckl/1)**

**Explanation:**

- `^` - asserts the start of the string
- `(?=.*:)` - positive lookahead to make sure that the line contains a `:`
- `[^:]*` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character that is not a `:`

Comment: Great @Potato, just one point to add to the answer, if you work with long lists etc., the best way is to make iterator over list. So in this case you should write smth like this:

   `items_list = ['Dog', 'cat', 'merry', 'computer', 'legolas', 'boromir', 'just velry long string']`

    `new_items_list = [item if re.findall(r'^(?=.*:)[^:]*', item) else 'None' for item in items_list ]`

Answer (score 0):

You need a capturing group:

```
pattern = '(.*):'  # this will match any and all characters up untill ":"
pattern = '([a-zA-Z])*:'  # this will match only letters
pattern = '([a-zA-Z0-9])*:'  # matches alphanumericals
```

> If you speak the search criteria, you'll easily remember how to recreate it on your own: capture "()" anything "." as many times as possible "*" until you see a semicolon ":".

Most importantly `re.search` will return None if there is no ":" in the search string.

Answer (score 0):

A non-regex way is to split with `:` and count the number of splits. If it is more than 1, get the first item, else, return None:

```
splits = s.split(':')
if len(splits) > 1:
    print(splits[0])
else:
    print(None)
```

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/OGcEEi).

You may also use a regex approach like

```
^([^:]*):
```

and grab Group 1 if there is a match. See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/aMJVPc/1).

**Details**

- `^` -  start of string
- `([^:]*)` - Capturing group 1: any 0+ chars other than `:`
- `:` - a `:` char.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/5Rs2Bo):

```
import re
strs= ['AbcS:sdaf', 'AbcSsdaf']
pattern= re.compile(r'([^:]*):') # re.match requires a match at  string start, ^ is redundant
for s in strs:
    m = re.match(pattern, s)
    if m:
        print(m.group(1))
    else:
        print(m)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `re.search(pattern, string.split(":")[0]).group()`